# I'm having two set Collection values.I want unmatch values should display?

Tags: java, collections

I'm having two set Collection values.I want unmatch values should display?

```
Set  sqlrno = new HashSet();
Set  accessrno = new HashSet();
```

values are like

sqlrno    :1, 2, 3

accessrno : 1, 2

Expected output : 3

I tried below code but doesn't work?

```
         for (Object collaccess : accessrno) {
             for (Object collsql : sqlrno) {
                 if (collsql != collaccess) {
                      System.out.println(collsql);
                 }
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`removeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29), remove from bigger collection

something like

```
Set<Integer>  sqlrno = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<Integer>  accessrno = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<Integer> result = null;
if(sqlrNo.size() > accessrno.size()){
 result = new HashSet<Integer>(sqlrno);
 result.removeAll(accessrno);
}else{
 result = new HashSet<Integer>(accessrno);
 result.removeAll(sqlrno);
}
```

Comment: Can please more elaborate